# SQL: Lots of one to many. Caching?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a root type which has many (10+) one to many relationships (each less than 20 secondaries) that are rarely, if ever, updated.

For most requests to my service I have to return a comma separated list of all indices that are referenced by the type.

Fetching all the data with LEFT OUTER JOINs and then constructing the list in my application with that takes multiple seconds which is not acceptable. Not surprising considering the queries now return an insane amount of rows.

My only idea to speed up the queries is caching the lists for the relationships in extra columns of my type or better in a separate table. That way the queries would always return the same amount of rows as the main type table. I'd setup triggers to update the lists for the rare cases the relations are updated (awful performance in those cases is not a problem).

But both, storing data multiple times and storing serialized data is considered bad practice.

Are there better options? Or is my idea reasonable?

Also note that I am working with sqlite.

Comment: What about (non persistent) caching at the application level?

Comment: Not entirely sure. There are about 10k entries for my type (unlikely to change by a significant margin). Creating hash maps for those might work out...

Comment: Do proper indexes supporting the query already exist? If not, you should look into that first.

Comment: I actually forgot to add some indices. The difference between no indices and all possible ones is only about 1/4 of the required query time.

Comment: The applications I work on cache “many millions” of items locally under normal operation, depending on need (application lifetime caches, time-refresh caches, LRU caches, even some longer lifetime memcached..) and it generally works out well. There is also mechanisms to force the application to re-validate it’s caches, as done after daily database updates. There are _very few_ places that we use DB-level caches, and we have multiple hundreds of tables and dozens of databases.. it’s easier to “fix” a temporal application cache than deal with long-term synchronization.

Comment: One could use SQLite itself as a temporal cache: don’t worry about long-term synchronization, as that’s an annoying burden..